# COM C# heavy load

Tags: c#, com+

I'm using a central COM+ component that invoking other C# classes via the following code:

```
var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NameSpace.Class1");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Class1.dll");
var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
```

Normally this peace of code is working fine. When simulate a heavy load on this central COM+ component the Activator can't create any instance. The class1 is not in the same folder as the central COM+ component.

I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'NameSpace, Class1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95a767s6d7'.
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetOrCreateProxy(Identity idObj, Object proxy, Boolean fRefine)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.InternalUnmarshal(ObjRef objectRef, Object proxy, Boolean fRefine)
  at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxyAttribute.CreateInstance(Type serverType)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
  at Dummy.CreateBusinessLayerInstance(Type businessLayerType, Boolean remoteObject)
```

Any ideas to solve the problem? When I create the instance via DCOM everything is fine.

Comment: is there any InnerException?

Comment: Unfortunately not.